# Is 'fed up OF' acceptable, shouldn't it be 'fed up WITH'?

Tags: grammar

Question really says it all.   "I am fed up of
television ?" just does not sound correct yet I hear it used all the time.

Comment: It is 'fed up with'. However, after a little research on internet I saw few references of 'fed up of' being heard.

Comment: If you hear it used all the time, then of course you will think it is correct.

Comment: In anything that has the slightest formality in writing, you would say "I'm fed up with ...", but in commonly used speech you might well hear "I'm fed up of TV.". And the word "of" is often a re-working of an un-stressed "have.": I should of caught the train earlier to get there in time.".  Who is to say it is incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

It is "fed up WITH" a thing/person.

I have heard "fed up OF" when followed with a phrase of these types:
- "I'm fed up OF having to pick up after you all the time."
- "I'm fed up OF working for the man."
These sound natural, however, I'm not sure if they are technically *correct*.
Substituting WITH in these cases also works.

Previous comments with regard to similarities to "bored with/of" -also can substitute the same phrases as above and will sound natural...

Comment: Afraid I still think your two later examples would sound better with 'with' if you see what I mean,

Comment: I agree - 'with' still sounds better